# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.IndexedUDFFinder

Tags: java, excel, maven, classnotfoundexception

I was running:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook([from a FileInputStream]);
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.IndexedUDFFinder
```

I have imported these packages:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

They depend on Maven pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The apache poi jar or one of its dependencies is not in your classpath at runtime.  How are you running it?

Answer (score 10):

I got this error because of version difference between poi(3.9) and poi-ooxml(3.10). Check your versions.
The correct one for me:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thx, It was the version difference that caused the problem

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following and it works just fine:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

---

```
InputStream myxls = new FileInputStream(fileName);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(myxls);
```

---

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This annoying problem is resolved by rebuilding the project to get the jars in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please post a brief explanation alongside your code. This will likely increase the usefulness of your post.